# safety of passing boost::shared_ptr reference

Tags: c++, boost, resourcemanager

my question is, how fail-safe is the following code snippet which is part of my resource manager:

```
 bool Load(std::string name, boost::shared_ptr<Asset::Model>& newModel)
 {
  std::map<std::string, boost::scoped_ptr<Asset::Model> >::const_iterator seeker;

  seeker = models.find(name);
  if (seeker == models.end())
   return false;

  newModel = seeker->second->Copy(); // Copy returns a boost::shared_ptr<Asset::Model>
  return true;
 }

private:
 std::map< std::string, boost::scoped_ptr<Asset::Model> >  models;
```

because passing boost's shared_ptr by reference is actually not part of the shared_ptr concept, if i only use it in this scope, could i run into trouble?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This usage is safe, in that whatever the `shared_ptr<>` passed in through the reference will have it's refcount reduced (assuming that the `shared_ptr<>` returned from `seeker->second->Copy()` isn't a `shared_ptr<>` to the same object) and therefore the object it will be pointing to might be deleted.

Specifically, you aren't creating a second `shared_ptr<>` from a raw pointer (which is an error because it would create a second, unrelated `shared_ptr<>` with a separate refcount, and therefore a second owner of the object).

Whether your function provides the behavior you want depends on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to do something like this:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Asset::Model> ptr;
if(Load("stuff", ptr))
{
     doSomething with ptr
}
```

In this case you should be fine.

However you don't need to use a reference here. Just return a `shared_ptr` and set it to 0 if no element was found:

```
 boost::shared_ptr<Asset::Model> Load(std::string name)
 {
  std::map<std::string, boost::scoped_ptr<Asset::Model> >::const_iterator seeker;
  boost::shared_ptr<Asset::Model> retPtr;

  seeker = models.find(name);
  if (seeker == models.end())
   return retPtr;

  retPtr = seeker->second->Copy(); // Copy returns a boost::shared_ptr<Asset::Model>
  return retPtr;
 }
```

However I noticed you are using `scoped_ptr` in a standard container - which AFAIK is not possible.

Comment: Well i dont want to return a shared_ptr in case the load fails. Thats why i return a bool